# How to get the variable value from adapter to activities in android kotlin recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a chat app in android using kotlin and wanted to create a group item based on registered users.

Currently I'm facing a problem on finding a way to pass the variable from the adapter going back to activities because i want to have a floating check button and display what are the selected users from that adapter.

I browse the web but haven't found an ideal write-up about adaptes to activites.

Please point me to some solutions/helpful articles about this. Or if this question is duplicated and answered successfully.

Thanks

AddUserGroupAdapter.kt

....

```
override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: AddUsersGroupAdapter.ViewHolder?, user : Users?, position: Int) {
        var userId = getRef(position).key

        viewHolder!!.bindView(user!!,context)


        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if(viewHolder.userSelected!!){
                viewHolder.userSelected = false
                //viewHolder!!.bindView(user!!,context)
                viewHolder.userCheck!!.visibility = View.GONE

            }else{
                viewHolder.userSelected = true
                viewHolder.userCheck!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            //TODO : I want to collect the Id's into list and 
            // will access to the activity(AddUserGroupActivity)
            //Toast.makeText(context,userId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }


    }
```

AddUserGroupActivity.kt

...

```
class AddUsersGroupActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var mUserDatabase : DatabaseReference? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_users_group)

        supportActionBar!!.setTitle("Add Users in Group")
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)



        var lineaLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Users")

        rvAddUsersGroup.setHasFixedSize(true)

        rvAddUsersGroup.layoutManager = lineaLayoutManager
        rvAddUsersGroup.adapter = AddUsersGroupAdapter(mUserDatabase!!, this)

        //TODO : This is where I wanted to have a floating action button onClickListener
        //that will access the variable from adapter and display to toast.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listerner to you `ViewHolder` which will notify your adapter and in adapter forward this notification to activity.

```
override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: AddUsersGroupAdapter.ViewHolder?, user : Users?, position: Int, userSelectionListener: (Users, Boolean) -> Unit) {
    var userId = getRef(position).key

    viewHolder!!.bindView(user!!,context)


    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        if(viewHolder.userSelected!!){
            viewHolder.userSelected = false
            //viewHolder!!.bindView(user!!,context)
            viewHolder.userCheck!!.visibility = View.GONE
           usersSelectionListener.invoke(user, true)

        }else{
            viewHolder.userSelected = true
            viewHolder.userCheck!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           usersSelectionListener.invoke(user, false)
        }

        //TODO : I want to collect the Id's into list and 
        // will access to the activity(AddUserGroupActivity)
        //Toast.makeText(context,userId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
}
```

Add same parameter to your Adapter constructor, then in activity handle this listener:

```
rvAddUsersGroup.adapter = AddUsersGroupAdapter(mUserDatabase!!, this) { user: User, isSelected: Boolean -> 
    //Do want you want with user and selection.
}
```

Comment: Hi @RediOne I try adding the last parameter but i got an error that it will remove the override in populateView...

Comment: I already make it work but rather adding the listener to populateView I add this to the class argument. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you could pass data from adapter to the activity by three ways

1. add CallBack
2. `(context.applicationContext as? BaseActivity)?.doSomething(variable)`
3. using Broadcast

but if you could get data from outside of Adapter by the number of pressed element, use

... Interface

```
interface  OnItemClickListener {
   fun onItemClick(index: Int)
}
```

... Adapter

```
var mOnItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
```

... Holder

```
 v.setOnClickListener {
            mOnItemClickListener?.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
```

... Activity

```
adapter.mOnItemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(index: Int) {
            mListener?.showDetails(index)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Artem where do you get the mOnItemListener?

Comment: create your own interface and then `var mOnItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null`

Comment: Hi thanks Artem, I up vote this but find the below answer much more readable. Thanks also

Comment: Thanks, finally found the answer for kotlin

Comment: Thank, you help me.